# Segmentation fault when importing numpy and calling Fortran library

Tags: python, numpy, cython

This is a strange one.

I am using Cython to build a Python package (let's call it `mypackage`) that wraps an external library (`externallib`). `externallib` is written in Fortran, but it has an interface library written in C. I use this C interface library to access `externallib` from Cython.

The development has been going very well, up to the point when I imported `numpy` or any other package dependent on `numpy` (e.g. `pint`, `matplotlib`, `pandas`, etc.) into the `mypackage.core` module (a `.pyx` file). I only import these packages, and do not even use them. This results in a segmentation fault.

```
Current thread 0x00007f02925ee740 (most recent call first):
  File "build/temp/mypackage/core_test.py", line 191 in _test_runner
  File "build/temp/mypackage/core_test.py", line 291 in test__str__
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/mypackage-build-python3.6.5/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 605 in run
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/mypackage-build-python3.6.5/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 653 in __call__
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/mypackage-build-python3.6.5/lib/python3.6/unittest/suite.py", line 122 in run
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/mypackage-build-python3.6.5/lib/python3.6/unittest/suite.py", line 84 in __call__
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/mypackage-build-python3.6.5/lib/python3.6/unittest/suite.py", line 122 in run
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/mypackage-build-python3.6.5/lib/python3.6/unittest/suite.py", line 84 in __call__
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/mypackage-build-python3.6.5/lib/python3.6/unittest/runner.py", line 176 in run
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/mypackage-build-python3.6.5/lib/python3.6/unittest/main.py", line 256 in runTests
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/mypackage-build-python3.6.5/lib/python3.6/unittest/main.py", line 95 in __init__
  File "build/temp/mypackage/core_test.py", line 311 in <module>
../build/scripts/build-package-linux.sh: line 151: 22796 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) python3 build/temp/mypackage/core_test.py
```

The segmentation fault occurs when I call a calculation routine in `externallib`, after I called it several times to provide input data for the calculation.

I know that numpy is also built with Fortran, C and Cython under the hood. Is there something obvious that I should be looking for to ensure compatibility between numpy and other C/Fortran external libraries? What could be causing the segmentation fault?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please use a debugger to find out exactly where it crashed, there is no other way. Then you will have to work from there, there is not enough information in the question to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @MatiasValdenegro. I know exactly where it crashes. It is when I do a calculation call to `externallib`. My question is not really about detailed code, but more about possible memory management risks related to numpy.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot give more details about `externallib`, since it is proprietary software. I am in conversation with the developers, though, and they will try to debug and find the problem on their side as well.

Comment: For your project to work, it is important to use a single compiler stack. In theory, you could mix C compilers but it makes it harder to debug if you have linking errors. Questions: what C and Fortran compilers did you use? I see that you use Anaconda, you must be aware that anaconda ships its own libgfortran that is most likely *not compatible* with the one installed by your system.

Comment: Hi @PierredeBuyl. I use gcc 7.3.0 to compile the Cython code. The Fortran library is proprietary, and I am unsure about their compiler. I think it is Intel. I also don't know what they use for their C wrapper around the Fortran library, but I will find out.

Comment: Hi @PierredeBuyl. The Fortran library and its C wrapper are compiled with gcc 6.3.0. I am using gcc 7.3.0. Could this be the cause of my misery?